# Error in ajax success function

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, post

I am creating a simple POST request to remove a user from the database. The DB operation goes through, but it gives me error when displaying the success function. Can anyone tell me what are the correct ajax headers I need to use for my AJAX request? I am using Tomcat 8.5 and jquery 3.2.0. Here is the JS code:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "./users/remove",
        type: "POST",
        method: "POST",
        data : {
          "userId" : data.userId,
          "userName" : data.userName 
        },
        success : function(data)
        {
          alert(data);
        },
        error : function()
        {
          alert("There was an unexpected error when removing the users.");
        }
    });
```

Java mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String removeUser(@RequestParam(value="userId") String userId, @RequestParam(value="userName") String userName, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
RFQVBOImpl bo = new RFQVBOImpl();
String responseMsg = bo.removeUser(userId); 
String alertMsg;

if(responseMsg.equals("TRUE") || responseMsg.equals("DUPLICATE"))
{
alertMsg = userName + " was removed successfully.";
}
else 
{
alertMsg = "There was an error when removing " + userName;
}

return alertMsg;
}
```

EDIT: I kept getting a generic 404 error in Javascript like this.

POST http://localhost:8080/rfqv/users/add 404 ()

send @ jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4

ajax @ jquery-3.2.0.min.js:4

(anonymous) @ view-users.js:107 //name of function being called.

dispatch @ jquery-3.2.0.min.js:3

q.handle @ jquery-3.2.0.min.js:3

---

I have added dataType : "text" to the ajax header and gotten the 405 error:
Request method 'GET' not supported

Description The method received in the request-line is known by the origin server but not supported by the target resource.
*I left the java method the same as above.

Comment: What is the error ??

Comment: I added the error and extra info in the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not about your headers. The problem is your handler is returning a `String`. If you are using `spring-mvc`, `Spring` by default considers that when a request handler returns a String it is a view, so it will try to find a view with that name.

To let Spring know you are not returning a view you need to use the `@ResponseBody` annotation:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain")
@ResponseBody
public String removeUser(@RequestParam(value="userId") String userId, @RequestParam(value="userName") String userName, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
  ...
}
```

You need to remove the type property from your ajax object and it should now expect, using the `dataType` property, a text response:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./users/remove",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "text",
    data : {
      "userId" : data.userId,
      "userName" : data.userName 
    },
    success : function(data)
    {
      alert(data);
    },
    error : function()
    {
      alert("There was an unexpected error when removing the users.");
    }
});
```

That should work, but what your really should do is return a json object. For you to get an idea something like:

```
public class RestResponse {
    private final boolean success;
    private final String message;

    public RestResponse(final boolean success, final String message)
    {
      this.success = success;
      this.message = message;
    }

    public boolean isSuccess()
    {
        return success;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {
      return message,
    }
}
```

Your controller still need to use `@ResponseBody` a return an instance of the previous class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/users/remove", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
@ResponseBody
public RestReponse removeUser(@RequestParam(value="userId") String userId, @RequestParam(value="userName") String userName, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
{
  ...

  if(responseMsg.equals("TRUE") || responseMsg.equals("DUPLICATE"))
  {
    return new RestReponse(true, userName + " was removed successfully.");
  }

  return new Response(false, "There was an error when removing " + userName);
}
```

And your ajax object needs to expect now a `json` response:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "./users/remove",
    method: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data : {
      "userId" : data.userId,
      "userName" : data.userName 
    },
    success : function(data)
    {
      alert(data.message);
    },
    error : function()
    {
      alert("There was an unexpected error when removing the users.");
    }
});
```

You could extend the `RestResponse` class to create an `ErrorRestResponse` and add a field to specify possible errors.

Comment: Thanks! This explains why my users/all method was working, but the others were not. Thanks for the tips on returning a JSON as a response, still rather new to spring.